# Unable to import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I am having a problem trying to import the org.apache project listed in the title into my Android for Eclipse project. I downloaded the JAR I need from

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonsio131sourcesjar.htm

And then right clicked my project, clicked build path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARS

After adding the build path to it, I still am getting the error message saying :

"The import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream cannot be resolved"

I am unsure why it isn't working.. any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have download and imported the jar & used `TeeOutputStream` Class  but no issues in eclipse, please download it from here

[Download Here](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi)

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much! I guess the one I downloaded was a bad version.